# How should I think about model selection when I will be aggregating predictions?

Tags: cross-validation, overfitting, aggregation

I'm estimating a model and then using it to predict values in another dataset. After predicting the values, I will aggregate the values to find averages within income quantiles.

I know the aggregation will lead to an estimate with reduced variance. I also know that an overfit model tends to have low bias in the training data, but high variance.

Should I be less concerned about overfitting since I'm aggregating estimates in the prediction data? How should I think about model selection and cross validation in this situation?

Note that I do need to predict the individual estimates before aggregating them, so that I can simulate public policy changes before aggregation.

Thanks,